# Running / executing Maven project quickly at the command line

Tags: maven

Looking at the Maven instructions:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

it says to build the target files with:

```
mvn package
```

and then to run the project, do:

```
java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
```

my question is - is there not a way to quickly run the project with something like:

```
mvn run mycompany.app
```

or something like that? If we use a convention or configuration, shouldn't there be some way to use `mvn` to run the project? O/w, I will just create a bash script to do the jar command, because that is way too much to type out every time!

Answer (score 0):

To run a Maven project, you would use something like this at the command line:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="suman.App"
```

I would guess that exec:java could be a default, and that -Dexec.mainClass could also be a default, thus there is probably some way to run it like so:

```
mvn exec "suman.App"
```

but that is just a guess.